# Question on "work" follows with a verb

Tags: verbs, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I am writing to inquire the correctness of the following sentence:

```
both work rely on this technique
```

Or

```
both work relies on this technique.
```

While the first one seems more grammarly correct, I do see some usages of the second case. Could any shed some lights on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a simple mistake. *Both* takes a plural NP, and *rely* is a plural verb.

I assume it is meant to be *Both works rely on this technique*.

(At first I couldn't make any sense of it at all, because "work" is usually uncountable. But once I realised that this must be art (or literature, or music) criticism, it makes sense).